# Sufficient condition for commutativity of finite rings

Tags: ring-theory, finite-rings

We know from Wedderburn's theorem any finite division ring is necessarily commutative.
Is there any other condition on finite rings which forces the ring to be commutative?

Comment: I want for finite rings. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not all that there is to be said about this, but see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring#Properties). Also [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S072308690600034X) is the article cited by that Wikipedia entry.

Comment: you know any condition particularly for finite rings? thanks.

Comment: @GArunkumar : the conditions in the Wikipedia entry applied equally for all commutative rings, that's not enough? Mind if I inquire what you need this for? Also, the second link I provided might have a condition you seek (I've not been through it all).